# ios issue with printing a value of variable on label

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with printing a value of variable on a label
and here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)sajil:(id)sender {

    [self.lana resignFirstResponder];
    [self.lahm resignFirstResponder];
    int lanafirst = _lahmNow.text;
    int lahmfirst = _lahmNow.text;
    int lanaNew   = _lana.text;
    int lahmNew   = _lahm.text;
    int lanaTotal = lanafirst + lanaNew;

    _lanaNow.text  =  lanaTotal;
    _lahmNow.text = _lahm.text;

}
```

I want `_lanaNow` to display the sum of the two textfields (`lana` and `lahm`). It currently does not display that value.

note : 
 `lana` and `lahm` are the two text-fields.

`_lanaNow` and `_lahmNow` are the two labels

Comment: printing NSLog u mean?

Comment: what is your problem here?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the desired behaviour, the actual behaviour and the actual error you are receiving. As it stands, your question just states that you are having a "problem". This is not enough information to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're assigning `NSString` variables to `int` variables, which does not work. 
If the user is entering numbers, `UITextField`'s `text` value will still be an `NSString`. To add together two inputs, do this

```
NSString *lanafirst = _lahmNow.text;
NSString *lahmfirst = _lahmNow.text;
NSString *lanaNew   = _lana.text;
NSString *lahmNew   = _lahm.text;
int total = lanaNew.intValue + lahmNew.intValue;
NSString *lanaTotal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", total];

_lanaNow.text  =  lanaTotal;
_lahmNow.text = _lahm.text;
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that I want the user to enter numbers :(
and with this way it doesn't calculate the sum